# CSS: Displaying absolute positioned element in Chrome

Tags: html, css, image, position, absolute

So I have the following CSS that positions an image that is set to a span tag:

```
.dc-mega-icon {
    background-image: url(...);
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 18px;
    width: 16px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 14px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<li class="liMenuItem" id="itemLogout">

    <a href="#" class="menuItem dc-mega">
        <span class="menuIcon">&nbsp;</span>
        My Profile
        <span class="dc-mega-icon"></span>
    </a>

    <div class="sub-container non-mega">
        <ul id="CCMenuOptions" class="sub" style="display: none;">
            <li class="mySupport"><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
            <li class="mySupport"><a href="#">My Support</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</li>
```

In Firefox/IE the arrow is displayed correctly:

[image]

IN CHROME the arrow is displayed on the left on top of the green icon:

[image]

Why does this happen? I noticed that in other WEbkit based brosers like Opera and Safari this doesn't happen only in Chrome.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue in Chrome. Possible to make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to demonstrate?

Comment: Honestly, it makes very little sense to go through the trouble of displaying something as an inline-block (twice, I might add), only to immediately position it absolutely. I would suggest abandoning the position absolute in favor of getting the element lined up correctly beside your text. Think of using position absolute as a way to remove something from the document flow, something which you don't want to obey the normal rules of pageflow. This arrow most certainly is not being displayed outside the page flow, so try updating the margins, padding and line-height to get this to work first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that Chrome is displaying it correctly. By default, `position: absolute` will display the element at `top: 0`, `left: 0`. You aren't using left or right to move the position at all. Try adding `right: 0` and see what happens. You also need `position: relative;` on the parent element.